# Instagram API https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nofilter/media/recent

Tags: tags, instagram-api

I am new in Instagram API. I am trying to get no of tag for 'nofilter' and likes but having issue with the URL.

https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nofilter/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&min_tag_id=123456
{"meta": {"error_type": "APIInvalidParametersError", "code": 400, "error_message": "min_id must not be a media id."}} Error

https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nofilter/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&min_tag_id='123456'
{"meta": {"error_type": "APIInvalidParametersError", "code": 400, "error_message": "min_id is not a valid cursor."}} Error

Could you please let me know how to get number of tags and likes.

Regards
Tarique Salaheen

Answer (score 0):

To get number of tag use this API, and look for `count`:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

To get all data of a tag use this API:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

This API response has the individual photo data with likes count per photo.

dont use the `min_tag_id`, it does not take any random value, thats the reason you are seeing the error, it is a encoded value that instagram generates and is available in the `pagination` of API response, it is used to get next set of posts.

Comment: Hi Krisrak:
I posted a photo with comment #gobigwinbig and #tariquesalaheen. The count tags returns 50 and 1 respectively but recent tags return with no data.
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/gobigwinbig?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
{"meta": {"code": 200}, "data": {"media_count": 50, "name": "gobigwinbig"}}
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/gobigwinbig/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
{"pagination": {"deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"}, "meta": {"code": 200}, "data": []}.
Regards
Tarique Salaheen

Comment: I think you are in sandbox mode?? are you using the access_token from the account you setup the sandbox? I checked the hashtags on https://www.picodash.com there are 28 and 1 photos.

Comment: Thanks Krisrak, Yes I am in sandbox. I will try today submit request for go live. Regards Tarique